# Has SymPy lost the functionality to divide by multiple polynomials?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomial-math

New to SymPy, and am experimenting with dividing polynomials. Currently, I am running Python 3.6.4 with SymPy 1.1.1 (pip installed). After browsing their documentation, I found on their [0.6.7 documentation page](https://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/polynomials.html#division) the following useful example:

> Another option is division by multiple polynomials at the same time. In general, the output is not unique and depends on the order of the divisors and the given monomial order (if specified).
>
> ```
> >>> f = x*y + y*z + z*x
> >>> g1 = x + 1
> >>> g2 = 2*y + 1
> >>> q, r = div(f, [g1, g2], x, y, z)
> >>> q
>                z
> [y + z, -1/2 + -]
>                2
> >>> r
>       3*z
> 1/2 - ---
>        2
> ```

However, this feature, at least in the [1.1.1 documentation page](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/basics.html#division) is non-existent. And, more so, if I try to attempt a similar operation on 1.1.1, I get the following error:

```
>>> f = x*y + y*z + z*x
>>> g1 = x + 1
>>> g2 = 2*y + 1
>>> q, r = div(f, [g1, g2], x, y, z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\[...]\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 4659, in div
    (F, G), opt = parallel_poly_from_expr((f, g), *gens, **args)
  File "C:\[...]\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 4266, in parallel_poly_from_expr
    return _parallel_poly_from_expr(exprs, opt)
  File "C:\[...]\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 4312, in _parallel_poly_from_expr
    raise PolificationFailed(opt, origs, exprs, True)
sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolificationFailed: can't construct polynomials from x*y + x*z + y*z, [x + 1, 2*y + 1]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\[...]\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py", line 4661, in div
    raise ComputationFailed('div', 2, exc)
sympy.polys.polyerrors.ComputationFailed: div(x*y + x*z + y*z, [x + 1, 2*y + 1]) failed without generators
```

I highly doubt this feature has been removed, as this is quite an important feature, especially for affine variate and Groebner basis analysis, (the topic I am studying)

Can someone point me toward a working example of this with SymPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is now available from the function [reduced](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.reduced). Using f, g1, g2 from your example,

```
>>> reduced(f, [g1, g2], x, y, z)
([y + z, z/2 - 1/2], -3*z/2 + 1/2)
```